# How to get multiple cases from text file with batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a config text file witch contains cases and i have to call another batch script for each case. My config txt looks like this, i have multiple cases with the same properties that are optional:

```
main:
  - case1:
     a: 123
     b: 321
     c: 654
  - case2: 
     b: 523
     d: 736
     a: 834
  - case3: 
     c: 231
     d: 246
```

I have to call the other script with the properties as arguments, (case3):

```
call script2.bat null null 231 246
```

I tried going through the text file with a for loop but i don't know how to separate the cases and call the second script with the right values. If possible i would like to use only batch.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   set line=%%a
   if "!line:~0,1!"=="a" (
      set a=!line:a: =!
   )
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to use `delims=:` to use `:` as a delimiter, then use `tokens=` to ensure you assign the left and right of each to a metavariable.

Comment: however, do you need to only use `case3`? and should both variables be sent to the second script at once?

Comment: There is 4 variables (a,b,c,d) if one is not in the case than it is null, i need to call all 3 case like these : 
call test.bat 123 321 654 null (case1)
call test.bat 834 523 null 736 (case2)

Comment: ok, give me a minute to post an answer.

Comment: I forgot to add that there can be more than 3 cases (we can add cases to the text file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the source directory & filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q71733362.txt"

SET "parmlist=a b c d"

FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=:- " %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF /i "%%b"=="main" FOR %%b IN (%parmlist% invalidlist) DO SET "%%b=null"
 FOR %%e IN (%parmlist%) DO IF /i "%%e"=="%%b" SET "%%e=%%c"&SET "invalidlist="
 SET "case=%%b"
 IF /i "!case:~0,4!"=="case" IF NOT DEFINED invalidlist (
  SET "params="
  FOR %%e IN (%parmlist%) DO SET "params=!params! !%%e!"&SET "%%e=null"
  ECHO CALL script2!params!
  SET "invalidlist=Y"
 )
)

IF NOT DEFINED invalidlist (
 SET "params="
 FOR %%e IN (%parmlist%) DO SET "params=!params! !%%e!"
 ECHO CALL script2!params!
)

GOTO :EOF
```

The `usebackq` option is only required because I chose to add quotes around the source filename.

Use `set "var1=data"` for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces.

I've use `if /i` throughout to make the string-match case-insensitive. Omit the `/i` if you want a case-sensitive match.

Set `parmlist` to a list of the parameters you wish to pass to `script2`.

Read the file using `:` `-` and <kbd>Space</kbd> as delimiters, assigning the first token found to `%%b` and the second to `%%c` (see `for /?` from the prompt or search a multitude of SO responses for documentation)

If the first token is `main`, set all of the variables in `parmlist` and the flag `invalidlist` to the value `null`.

Attempt to match the first token to the values in `parmlist`. on a match, set the value of the parameter found to the second token and set `invalidlist` to *nothing* which undefines `invalidlist`.

set `case` to the value of the first parameter, and examine the first 4 characters. If these match `case` and `invalidlist` is undefined (so a parameter has been defined) then build `params` by adding <kbd>Space</kbd>the value found (or `null` if no value has been found for that case) for each of the parameters in the list. and set the parameter value back to `null`.

I've `echo`ed the script2 call for verification purposes. Remove the `echo` keyword to actually execute `script2`.

The parameter values have now all been reset to `null`, so set `invalidlist` to a value since the list is now invalid.

At the end, if `invalidlist` is not set, we've got the last case built, so generate the `call` for that last case.

Note: I've assumed that the values  for the parameters are never negative, for lack of information otherwise.

---

In response to comment - 'case' may be some other string

```
SET "invalidlist=Y"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=:- " %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%c" equ "" (
  IF /i "%%b"=="main" (
   FOR %%b IN (%parmlist% invalidlist) DO SET "%%b=null"
  ) ELSE (
   IF NOT DEFINED invalidlist (
    SET "params="
    FOR %%e IN (%parmlist%) DO SET "params=!params! !%%e!"&SET "%%e=null"
    ECHO CALL script2!params!
    SET "invalidlist=Y"
   )
  )
 ) ELSE FOR %%e IN (%parmlist%) DO IF /i "%%e"=="%%b" SET "%%e=%%c"&SET "invalidlist="

)

IF NOT DEFINED invalidlist (
 SET "params="
 FOR %%e IN (%parmlist%) DO SET "params=!params! !%%e!"
 ECHO CALL script2!params!
)
```

The above procedure in place of the original `for` loop and clean-up should allow any single word (except `main`) to be used in place of `case`

A line containing a single word with any number of leading or trailing delimiters will cause `%%b` to contain the word and `%%c` to be an empty string, so test for that condition and test `%%b`  for `main` - initialise variables or *something-else* - output any accumulated data.

If `%%c` contains something, then try to put it into the appropriate variable as before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this:

```
@echo off
set cnt=0 & set casen=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1-3*delims=: " %%i in ('type test.txt ^| findstr /V "main:"') do (
    set "line=%%i %%j"
    set /a cnt+=1
    if "%%i" == "-" (
       set "case=!casen!"
       set /a casen+=1
       set cnt=
       for %%f in (a b c d) do set "_%%f=null"
  )
  for %%f in (a b c d) do if "%%f" == "%%i" set "_%%f=%%j"
  set "case!casen!=!_a! !_b! !_c! !_d!"
)
for %%e in (1,1,%casen%) do echo call script2.bat !case%%e!
```

It is possible to shorten it even more, but I have spent time to one point and you already have an accepted answer. So feel free to improve on it if you feel like doing so.